# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't wake up monitor

Tags: 20.04, external-monitor

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my Oryx Pro (oryp5) from System76. I have a Dell P2715Q monitor attached via USB-C. When the laptop goes to sleep the monitor doesn't wake up! My only solution at the moment is to unplug the USB-C cable on the laptop and plug it in again. Is there a better way?

When the monitor first goes blank I'm able to wake it up. But when I leave it for 20-30 minutes at least it doesn't wake up at all.

I tried reading many of the other solution on here for earlier versions of Ubuntu to no avail.

I have gnome-tweaks to prevent laptop from suspending when the lid is closed if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally the answer to my problem was this. I installed `laptop-mode-tools` like so:

```
sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools
```

Open the ui and check the mark next to "Enable module video-out". Seems to work for me!

Comment: I have a Darter Pro that is running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS with kernel 5.8.0-41-generic. This is not working for me. @KVISH did you try other steps?