# USB-C VGA Monitor doesn't wake up

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, suspend, 20.04, usb-c

I am running Ubuntu on an Intel NUC8i7HVK. It's worked seamlessly through three versions of Ubuntu, but on the upgrade to 20.04 has developed a problem.

One of my three monitors is connected via a USB-C to VGA device

```
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 04b4:5210 Cypress Semiconductor Corp. Billboard Device
```

This monitor *never* responds to wake up now.

When the displays sleep, either on reboot or lock, this monitor won't wake back up. The only way to get it back is to disconnect the USB-C device, wait for the monitors to reshuffle themselves, then plug it back in. This doesn't always work on the first try - sometimes it take four or five tries to make it work. [Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't wake up monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234662/ubuntu-20-04-doesnt-wake-up-monitor) looked promising, but that solution didn't work. Any thoughts would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After some messing around with different options, I settled on `xset -dpms` to just turn off DPMS. That prevents the monitors (all of them, sadly) from going to sleep. It's a functional workaround, but it would be nice to see a proper solution at some point